# Alias column name for Use in CASE Statement

Tags: sql

I have SQL query as below:

```
SELECT a.ID as AID, a.Amt as AAmt
FROM
     (SELECT
          ID,                       
          CASE
              WHEN Col1 = 0
                 THEN SUM (Col2 + Col3)
                 ELSE 0
          END AS Amt
      FROM  table1
      GROUP BY ID, Amt) AS a
```

I get an error:

> Invalid column name 'Amt'.

(note: this applies to the GROUP BY clause).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `GROUP BY` the alias,

Try

```
SELECT a.ID as AID, a.Amt as AAmt
FROM
     (SELECT
          ID,                       
          CASE
              WHEN Col1 = 0
                 THEN SUM (Col2 + Col3)
                 ELSE 0
          END AS Amt
      FROM  table1
      GROUP BY ID, Col1) AS a
```

If you have a look at [SQL Query Order of Operations](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/70-sql-query-order-of-operations.htm) you will note the the order of operations are

```
1.FROM clause
2.WHERE clause
3.GROUP BY clause
4.HAVING clause
5.SELECT clause
6.ORDER BY clause
```

This means that the `GROUP BY` is processed before the `SELECT`, which is where you defined the alias.

This also explains why you can order by an alias.

Comment: I get the error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @yankygo, try again please, I made a change to the `GROUP BY` section

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems a bit overly complicated, and the intention doesn't fully make sense.  I suspect you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT ID,  SUM(CASE WHEN col1 = 0 THEN col2 + col3 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM  table1
GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: Yep, That's smart. Done that, and greatly simplified the code (although the actual code is much larger than the redacted one i posted). And also didn't return NULL records for joined table.